# Microsoft Azure Database Android

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am able to successfully retrieve username from the table, but no other details.

[Database table name - User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmGMg.png)
[When i use api calls, it shows me this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XROT8.png)

Part of my code to which displays NULL error

```
private void refreshItemsFromTable() {

    System.out.println("[refreshItemsFromTable]");
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                final MobileServiceList<User> result =
                        mUserTable.select("id").execute().get();


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                           for (User item : result){
                             System.out.println("[Querying: ]"+item);
                           }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception e(1)");
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    runAsyncTask(task);
}
```

The below code is my user class.

```
public class User {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
    private String mId;

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("UserName")
    public String mUsername;

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("UserId")
    private int mUserId;

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("Password")
    public String mPassword;

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("deleted")
    public Boolean mDeleted;

    public User() {

    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getUsername();
    }
    public User(String id,int mUserId,String username,String password) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setUsername(username);
        this.setUserId(mUserId);
        this.setPassword(password);
    }
    public final void setId(String id){
        mId = id;
    }

    public final void setUsername(String username) {
        mUsername = username;
    }

    public final void setUserId(int mUserId) {
        mUserId = mUserId;
    }

    public final void setDeleted(Boolean deleted){
        mDeleted = deleted;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return mUsername;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return mId;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return mUserId;
    }

    public Boolean getDeleted(){
        return mDeleted;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return mPassword;
    }

    public void setPassword(String mPassword) {
        mPassword = mPassword;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof User && ((User) o).mId == mId;
    }

}
```

Error log

```
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.954 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.973 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.974 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.974 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.974 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.974 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.974 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.974 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.974 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.974 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.976 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.977 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.979 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.979 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.979 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.979 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.979 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.979 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.979 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.979 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.979 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
03-03 09:57:50.979 2150-2165/? I/System.out: [Querying: ]null
```

Please help me detect the error. Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming your code throws an exception.  What's the exception?  Are there any records in the table?

Comment: Yes, there are records in table. There is no exception thrown. It only returns null